# Prove that $\chi_l(K_{2,4})=3$

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that $\chi_l(K_{2,4})=3$

Note that $\chi_l (K_{2,4})$ is the list-chromatic number of $K_{2,4}$. I know that $\chi_l (K_{2,4})\geq \chi (K_{2,4})=2$

So first I need to show that $\chi_l (K_{2,4})\geq 3$, assume the contrary that $\chi_l (K_{2,4})=2$. Let $u_i$ be the vertices of the partite that only have 2 vertices, and $v_i$ be the vertices of the remaining partite.

I need to show that there is one collection of list $L$ doesn't work. I tried almost all the list of length 2, but nothing seem works. Any hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign disjoint color list to the small partite set, like $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$.
Now assign the 4 possible combinations to the 4 vertices of the large partite set
$(13,14,23,24)$.

This method generalizes to $K_{n,n^n}$.

For the other direction we show that each 3-list assignment allows a proper coloring.
Color the small partite set first. You can use any of the available colors since their vertices are independent. Now each vertex of the large partite set has only two neighbours, and since it has three available colors, a proper coloring can be completed.

Comment: so you use 4 colors for this one, that mean I can use as much color as I wish, the number of color doesn't necessarily be the same as $\chi_l(G)$ ?

Comment: your answer show that $\chi_l(K_{2,4}) \geq 3$ can I conclude that because  $\chi_l(K_{2,4})$ is the smallest length of the list coloring that work, so the smaller of $\chi_l(K_{2,4}) \geq 3$ is $3$? or I need to show $\chi_l(K_{2,4}) \leq 3$ as well?

Comment: You can use as many colors as you want, it is only the list size that is relevant here. It is very easy to prove that $\chi_l(K_{2,n})\leq3$ for all $n\geq 4$. Try it yourself first, if you fail I will help.

Comment: thank you, I will try that, and ask you again if I have anymore question, I really want to understand these stuff. Thank you very much again.

Comment: To show $\chi_l(K_{2,n}) \leq 3$, I need to use induction, right? However, at the base, can you tell me how to show this is work for every list of coloring length 3? The term "every" kinda scare me off, I tried greedy algorithm and the formula that say $\chi_l(G) \leq 1+ \Delta(G)$, but nothing work for $K_{2,4}$

Comment: No induction. I have expanded the answer. But don't tell me the proof is difficult :)

Comment: oh, so this is similar to prove $\chi(G) \leq k$, but now you use a list of coloring. I think I kinda understand it now, but I  need to practice a lot more to get used to it. Thank you very much for your help.